# Can not group by queryset django

Tags: python, django

I have a queryset like this:
<QuerySet [{'company_id': 999, 'сurrent_burn_rate': Decimal('70125.00')}, {'company_id': 999, 'сurrent_burn_rate': Decimal('2892.00')}, {'company_id': 999, 'сurrent_burn_rate': Decimal('32811.00')}}]>

All company_id are 999. I want to group by it by id and make sum of сurrent_burn_rate.
I make this code:

Objects.all().values('company_id').annotate(total=Sum('сurrent_burn_rate'))

I expected:
<QuerySet [{'company_id': 999, 'total': 'Toal sum of all records with id 999'}]>

But get:

<QuerySet [{'company_id': 999, 'total': Decimal('70125.00')}, {'company_id': 999, 'total': Decimal('2892.00')}, {'company_id': 999, 'total': Decimal('32811.00')}}]>

why it is don't work?

Comment: Share your models. Is company_id a foreign key?

Comment: Yes. company is  foreign key

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use **aggregate** method.

```py
Objects.filter(company_id=999).aggregate(total=Sum('сurrent_burn_rate'))
```

Comment: more here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregations-and-other-queryset-clauses

Comment: Thank you, yes it is correct case. I know I can do like this. but I'm interested in finding out why the grouping by values and annotation doesn't work